# RCTView generated view config for validAttributes does not match native

Tags: android, react-native, mobile

React Native application loads then crashes even though it was working a week ago.

The error generated is:

`RCTView generated view config for validAttributes does not match native, missing: onPointerOut onTouchCancel onStartShouldSetResponder onTouchStart gap onStartShouldSetResponderCapture onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture columnGap onPointerLeaveCapture onTouchEnd accessibilityCollection onResponderTerminationRequest...`

I've tried:

- Uninstalling the app,
- Deleting the build folder in android folder,
- Reinstalling node packages,
- Resetting npm cache

The application usually just launches with no errors.

Comment: im having the same issue, did u find a fix for it?

Comment: Negative. I'm waiting for the latest react-native, and upgrading all the way. If I keep seeing it, and find a way to resolve it, I'll holler back.

Comment: So, we moved to the latest version... During that time, however, I found a random file called `ios-remove-webview.js`... which removed a bunch of RTC*.h and RTC*.m files. Didn't test if it was the issue, but it definitely looked sus. See if you have something like that.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I think my previous comment is the answer. I don't have any other ideas. Highly recommend updating.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was due to version mismatches in expo, react,  react-native, I have deleted all node modules and installed with appropriate versions
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSZIk.png)

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, we updated our codebase to the latest react-native version, got rid of some `ios-remove-webview.js` which removed a bunch of RTC*.h and RTC*.m files... and tada! The issues went away.

I think the answer here is: update your codebase.